# Convert Tor keypair to hex or base64 format

Tags: openssl, tor, cryptography, public-key-encryption, hexadecimal

I just generated a Tor key with [mkp224o](https://github.com/cathugger/mkp224o), and I ended up with this (example) output file:

```
== ed25519v1-secret: type0 ==∏—
¯£«•
UJ’Î˙Ù¬
§π¯_˚ÑÆE Œ«ß˝†òyﬂsk¸¬ì–Ôâm
ù≤Ü(~”ö}Ù
```

I want to get a hexadecimal or base64 representation of this secret key. If I generate an ed25519 key with OpenSSL, I can do this to get the hexadecimal representation:

```shell
openssl ec -in ./my_ed25519.pem -text
```

However, the Tor key that I generated is obviously not in PEM format.

**How can I view the raw hexadecimal (or base64) value of my generated private key?** And how can I view the raw hexadecimal (or base64) value of the corresponding public key?